# How to completely uninstall VS Code on Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

What is the way to totally uninstall Visual Studio Code and its extensions, including all configurations, etc.) on Windows 10?

I tried uninstalling and installing but it remembered its previous settings.

Answer (score 108):

Since, you might already know the drill to uninstall and you are emphasizing on **`remembered its previous settings`**, please do the following:

1. Open Run (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Type `%appdata%`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Delete the folder `Code`

Voila! Restart Visual Studio Code and it is reset!

Here is a bat script which does the same thing:

```bash
explorer.exe %appdata%
del Code
```

> P.S: Since, you want to uninstall go to `Add or Remove Programs` and click on bottom right of the `Visual Studio Code` tile, where it says `Uninstall`.

Comment: Create the bat file using notepad, give it a name and save it, it would work.

Comment: Do we have to restart Windows for it to take effect? I deleted the Code folder, but my machine still has it available as an app.

Comment: Extensions are installed inside C:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode
We MUST also DELETE that folder.

Answer (score 49):

Here is the complete solution you can apply:

1. Go to where Visual Studio Code is installed and invoke 'uninst000.exe'.
   In my case it is installed in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`
2. Delete directory `%APPDATA%\Code`
3. Delete directory `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`

Comment: I guess I should be smarter but I started at the top.  DO NOT DELETE THE .CODE dir.  It is for Visual Studio NOT VSCOde.  I had several highly configured projects and ALL of their settings are lost.

Answer (score 36):

Turns out the extensions are stored under `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`. Deleting that gets rid of them.

Answer (score 9):

Go to Path: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code`

Double Click 
`uninstall.exe`

This will uninstall VS Code from Your Windows OS
and

After uninstallation delete `code` folder also.

`Open Run (Win + R)` and Enter `%appdata%` Press Enter

Delete the folder `code`.

Comment: I guess I should be smarter but I started at the top. DO NOT DELETE THE .CODE dir. It is for Visual Studio NOT VSCOde. I had several highly configured projects and ALL of their settings are lost. RTFQ!!

Answer (score 7):

Easy way to remove it

> Step1: to find VSCode path
>   Example:  C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

[image]

> Step2: to run unins000.exe

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you use the word **Completely**, I would say

1. Do the regular Uninstall in "Apps & features."
2. In strat, search "environment variable" and remove all the *references for `Visual Studio Code* or *any installation path*.
3. In file Explore, type `%APPDATA%` and remove the folder called `Code.`
4. And got to `%LOCALAPPDATA%` and deleted the folder `code` if it exists.
5. Got to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming` and remove the folder `code`

> **This will remove all your configurations and the extensions**

FYI: [Uninstall Visual Studio Code by code.visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall)

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that can asure any trace if a file is removed, go ahead to your sudo user

In ubuntu:
`sudo -i`, others might use `sudo - su`

then you want to proceed with the global search, then you must run:

find / -name "*vscode*"

You will probably end up having a lot of permission denied, but that's ok. we don't want to access them anyways.

Now you'll end up with a big list of files to remove, so you can go one by one and ensure you're in fact removing them OR...

you can just run `find / -name "*vscode*" | grep vscode | xargs rm -rf`