# TSLint extension can not be installed in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

TSLint hangs during installation in an infinite loop.

[image]

I tried already this methods.

[Uninstall visual studio code in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689536/uninstall-visual-studio-code-in-windows)

Deleted Extensions in Folder %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions

[image: Screenshot Explorer]

Uninstalled and reinstalled via NPM TyperScript and TSLint

$ npm install -g tslint typescript

$ npm uninstall -g tslint typescript

[image: Screenshot Terminal]

Also I uninstalled and reinstalled VSCode V1.23.1

Someone knows a solution?