# Error when trying to use .NET Generate Assets for Building and Debug in VSCode

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'll make this brief, below is the main issue I'm having.

I'm learning C# again so I can expand my skillset. Long story short, the tutorial I was following was showing the viewer how to use the above command from VSCode's command palette.

Whenever I try to use said command to generate the files it should, I get the error: "Unable to generate assets to build and debug. OmniSharp server is not running."

Thus far I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the C# Extension in VSCode
- Added C:\Windows\System32 to my PATH environment variable
- Doing the above plus completely deleting the original project folder, restarting my computer, and remaking the simple "Hello world" print program created using "dotnet new console", inside of a workspace.

I am using:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio Code 1.48.2
- .NET SDK 3.1.401

I'm not sure what other information may be necessary, and I've looked through other similar questions, but nothing I try works, even after restarting my machine. I'm at a loss frankly.

Comment: Is there any error when reinstalling VSCode?, look for any error while running VSCode.  Try to do a full reinstall, look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689536/uninstall-visual-studio-code-in-windows

Comment: @jmsalcido Just did a completely fresh reinstall of VS Code onto my machine. Took down everything, all associated files and directories, all of it. There were no errors when reinstalling.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the C# Extension on the current version is just buggy and not working right. Downloading an older version (1.21.16) and installing from VSIX seems to have somewhat fixed the previous issue. At the very least the error message has changed to something else.

For anyone also having this issue, I recommend trying what I did.