# VS Code extensions are unresponsive

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's no indication of anything in the status bar, but the Extensions tab has a clock on it and I cannot perform certain actions in the tab, such as upgrade extensions or install them in WSL. The buttons are dimmed/'grayed out.'

[image]

This absolutely will not go away. What can I do about this?

EDIT: @WilsonPena suggested I see if there are any errors in the console and, indeed, I found one:

```
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] (node:4076) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.(Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
S @ console.ts:137
```

I'm assuming the several Warnings I see in the console are probably not to blame, but this Error most definitely looks like the culprit.

Comment: open the `Command Palette` (View>Command Paletter or press Ctrl+Shift+P) then search for the option `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` then click on the console tab and check if there some errors that might help solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, @WilsonPena; I've added the error message to the question.

Comment: That error is there already for many versions, the clock might show when there are updates made to extensions

Comment: Indeed, @rioV8, before the clock appears, a circle with "6" shows up briefly in that spot. Then it becomes a clock and stays that way forever. There are definitely 6 extensions that can be updated, but I cannot update them. In addition, this only happens when VS Code is in a Remote session with WSL. (I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 and have been for quite some time. This issue is recent, however.)

Answer (score 1):

Might be your issue can trace out through VS setting JSON file.
If any un-stable extensions are configured and which affected the configuration means you can open the setting.json file

VS Code provides two different scopes for settings:

User Settings - Settings that apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open.
Workspace Settings - Settings stored inside your workspace and only apply when the workspace is opened.

Workspace settings override user settings. Workspace settings are specific to a project and can be shared across developers on a project.

By default VS Code shows the Settings editor, but you can still edit the underlying settings.json file by using the Open Settings (JSON) command or by changing your default settings editor with the workbench.settings.editor setting.

Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:

```
Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

The workspace settings file is located under the .vscode folder in your root folder.

One sample setting JSON is added here, please check your file and revert if any extension wrongly installed.

[image]

Comment: I've checked all `settings.json` files (User, Workspace, and WSL - Ubuntu). None of them exhibit any abnormalities. I'm not sure how to tell if an extension is 'wrongly installed,' though.

Comment: So I decided to just wipe out all extensions and settings based on the top two answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689536/uninstall-visual-studio-code-in-windows). Since it is no longer endlessly spinning, I can begin installing my extensions, one-by-one, until I find the culprit(s) that were causing problems. @Nayana, since you are the only one who answered and identified that an extension is to blame, I'll award the bounty to you. Thank you. I'll update this later when I've identified the bad extension.

Comment: Thank you @Strum and am suggesting you just uninstall and install again VS code if still not working.

Comment: So, it turns out that it's not 'a bad extension'. I still don't have an answer, but I _can_ identify that much. The reason is that, after install a handful of extensions, attempting to then install them in WSL exhibits the same old behavior. And this is _after_ having wiped everything out as much as I could! One other thing that might help pinpoint the problem is that even VS Code's Source Control panel doesn't recognize that I have git on a workspace when it's remotely connected to WSL.