# VS Code not activating extensions

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I´m having problems and I can´t figure out how to fix them. Since the last update (1.57.0) my VS Code is not working was expected. First it prompt me when opening a folder if I trust the authors, I check yes and then I put my parent folder with all my projects.

After two days the Git extension started to show me the message "The folder currently open doesn't have a git repository.". But there the folder has a git repository, and if got to terminal I can use all the git features.

[image: The folder currently open doesn't have a git repository.]

I notice that no extensions are loaded:

[image: no extensions]

If I change the folder to another project several times, after a while finally the extension is loaded, even in a folder that hasn´t loaded before, I can see the "Activating Extensions..." message at the status bar:

[image: Activating Extensions...]

I´ve searched for this problem in many sites, forums, vscode repository issues and nothing help me. When I open the "Output" tab I notice that there are no extensions output.

[image]

I already tried to uninstall and install VS Code again with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fix it doing a complete uninstall of VS Code:

1. Use the uninstall: "%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/uninst000.exe"
2. Delete directory "%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Roaming/Code"
3. Delete directory "%USERPROFILE%/.vscode"

Source: [Uninstall visual studio code in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59401593/404018)

Comment: I had this issue when I was working remotely on a project and there was no space left on the device. It got resolved when I cleared some space off the device.

Comment: I had the git extension issue when I was working with ssh-remote, it was constantly trying to activate the extension, but without success.
I tried several approaches (reload, reload with extensions disabled and enable them, disable @builtin git extension), but the only helped is to reboot the remote virtual machine, where the vscode-server was running.

P.S. my issue started when I was changing the code not in the editor, but in the "working tree diff" editor and in the middle of it my internet connection was lost. After it was re-established - git extensions stopped working